# Get enumerated values with a reasoner

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, owl-api, reasoning

Assumedly I have a data property named `fooType` with 2 possible values `{"Low", "High"}`:

```
<DataPropertyRange>
    <DataProperty IRI="#fooType"/>
    <DataOneOf>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">Low</Literal>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">High</Literal>
    </DataOneOf>
</DataPropertyRange>
```

How can I use owlapi and a reasoner to:

1. Get all ranges of data property fooType (gets "Low" and "High")
2. Get all fooType values of a given individual?

So far I've tried and stucked:

```
// 1. How to get "Low" and "High" strings in the next step?
OWLDataProperty dataProperty = ...
Set<OWLDataPropertyRangeAxiom> dataPropertyRangeAxioms = ontology.getDataPropertyRangeAxioms(dataProperty);

// 2. How to get fooType's values in the next step?
OWLIndividual individual = ...
Set<OWLLiteral> literals = reasoner.getDataPropertyValues(individual, dataProperty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasoner is not necessary to list all enumerated values - for example, it will not list values that are not used but allowed to be used in the enumeration.

To access all ranges and their components:

```
OWLOntology o = ...
OWLDataProperty p = ...
o.dataPropertyRangeAxioms(p)
    .map(OWLDataPropertyRangeAxiom::getRange)
    .forEach((OWLDataRange range) -> 
        // this is where you can visit all ranges
        // using an OWLDataRangeVisitor
    )
);
```